# Is a strict schedule always serializable?

Tags: database, concurrency

In DBMS, is a strict schedule always serializable?

If the answer is no, then please provide an example of a strict schedule which is not serializable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Every serializable schedule is strict.
But every strict schedule is not serializable.

[image: Schedules heirarchy]

A Schedule is a serializable schedule if its outcome is equal to the outcome of its transactions executed serially i.e. without interleaving the transactions.

Whereas, a strict schedule is the one in which some other transaction T2 cannot read or write the data written by T1 unless it is committed.

So for example,[image: Strict schedule which is not serializable]

In other words in Strict schedule T2 can read the data which is being read by T1, but once T1 writes the data, from that time to the time it commits, T2 cannot read or write the data.

Answer (score 4):

(For the following, I assume conflict-serializability.)

No, a strict schedule is not always serializable. The following schedule is strict (no reading from or overwriting of data items before a commit), but not serializable (there are two conflict pairs: r_1[x] and w_2[x] & w_2[x] and w_1[x], but they are ordered differently). The operations with subscript 1 belong to transaction T_1, those with subscript 2 to transaction T_2.

```
r_1[x] w_2[x] c_2 w_1[x] c_1
```

Contrary to the answer given above, a serializable schedule is not necessarily strict. See the following example:

```
w_1[x] w_2[x] c_2 r_1[y] c_1
```

Transaction T_2 overwrites the w_1[x] of T_1 before the commit of T_1. Nevertheless, the schedule is (conflict-)equivalent to the serial schedule T_1 T_2.

Answer (score -2):

" Strict schedule is always serializable ".    This  statement is False.

Click on the image to view.
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4GxAv.png)

You can see here, this schedule is strict but it is not serializable. There is cycle in precedance graph.